Android: lifecycleScope.launch not working inside LiveData observer after Orientation change
I have the following code in my Activity which i call in onCreate
val carFlow: Flow<Car> = carFlowProvider.provideFlow()
viewModel.testingLiveData.observe(this, Observer { testValue ->
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                        refreshCar(carFlow.firstOrNull(), testValue)
                    }
                }
        })

This works fine on first activity launch and refreshCar() method is called with available value of Car from carFlow.
But after screen rotation, when ViewModel posts a new testValue into testingLiveData, the launch block is called but carFlow.FirstOrNull() doesn't execute and so refreshCar() method is never called.
This happens only after screen rotation.
Thanks
Tried using repeatOnLifecycle(STARTED) but that didn't work either

are you sure there is a value in the carFlow? Flow does not save its last value on rotation

Seems like you should have collect on the carFlow somewhere... what does testingLiveData even do?  Instead of the posting to the live data, the view model could emit a new Car.  Also you might want a StateFlow so you can access the last value after rotation.
